Computable subsets of non-standard models of arithmetic
By Tennenbaum's theorem, there exists no computable non-standard model of $\mathsf{PA}$. That is, for any nonstandard model $M$, we cannot define an encoding of the integers $x\in M$ such that $+_M$, $\times_M$, $<_M$ are computable functions on this encoding.
However, this isn't necessarily an issue for subsets of non-standard models: in fact, for certain sets of operations $\mathcal O$, we can find a subset $M_{\mathcal O}$ such that

$\mathbb N\subset M_{\mathcal O}$, i.e., $M_{\mathcal O}$ contains all standard integers and some non-standard integers in $M$;
$M_{\mathcal O}$ is closed under $\mathcal O$;
the integers $x\in M_{\mathcal O}$ can be encoded such that the operations in $\mathcal O$ are computable, and further, the integers $x\in\mathbb N$ can be computably decoded to their standard values.

For a simple example, take $\mathcal O=\{+,-,\times,\lfloor\div\rfloor,\operatorname{mod},<\}$. First, we take some non-standard integer $\xi\in M\setminus\mathbb N$, and set $\omega=\xi!$, so that $\omega\equiv0\pmod k$ for all $k\in\mathbb N^+$. Then, our $M_{\mathcal O}$ is the set of integers $x=a_0+\frac{a_1}{b_1}\omega+\frac{a_2}{b_2}\omega^2+\dots+\frac{a_n}{b_n}\omega^n$, where $n\in\mathbb N,a_i\in\mathbb Z,b_i\in\mathbb N^+,$ and $a_n>0$ (except for $x=0$, which has $a_0=0$). Addition, multiplication, and comparison are trivial. To compute $\lfloor\frac xy\rfloor$, we perform polynomial long division, then round down any fractional $a_0$; from there, we can take $x\bmod y=x-y\lfloor\frac xy\rfloor$. Thus, all operations on our $M_{\mathcal O}$ are computable, and any standard value can be decoded.
It turns out that we can extend $\mathcal O$ somewhat further. Let $d_b(x,y)$ denote the digit at $b^y$ in the base-$b$ expansion of $x$. Then, there is seemingly a construction which lets us add $\{d_2(x,y),\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor,2^x\}$ to $\mathcal O$, alongside the usual bitwise operators $\{\operatorname{AND},\operatorname{OR},\operatorname{XOR},\operatorname{popcount},\dots\}$. Here, let $b\uparrow\uparrow x$ denote tetration, as in $b\uparrow\uparrow0=1,b\uparrow\uparrow(x+1)=b^{b\uparrow\uparrow x}$. Then, take some $\xi\in M\setminus\mathbb N$ as before, and set $\omega=2\uparrow\uparrow\xi$. For our encoding, we first define a descending sequence $\omega_0=\omega,\omega_{k+1}=\log_2(\omega_k)$. Then, we start with base values $x=0$ and $x=\omega_k$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, and recursively construct new values $$x=\frac{a_1\cdot2^{p_1}+a_2\cdot2^{p_2}+\cdots+a_n\cdot2^{p_n}}{b_1\cdot2^{q_1}+b_2\cdot2^{q_2}+\cdots+b_m\cdot2^{q_m}},$$ where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb Z,a_n>0,b_m>0,$ the exponents $p_i,q_i\in M_{\mathcal O}$ were constructed in an earlier step, and the two values are divisible.
I haven't fully explored the full range of possibilities with non-standard divisors (e.g., I'm not sure exactly how to check divisibility). But if we restrict ourselves only to standard divisors, we find that the bits of $x$ are grouped into a finite number of "segments", each with an initial part and a periodic part that runs to the next segment. For instance, $(\omega-1)^2/15$ has a binary expansion of $$\overbrace{1000\,1000\cdots1000\,1000}^{\omega_1-4\text{ bits}}\,\overbrace{0111\,0111\cdots0111\,0111}^{\omega_1\text{ bits}}\,1_2.$$ With judicious use of Euler's theorem, this simple structure allows us to determine $d_2(x,y)$ for any $y$, as well as the other bitwise operators. In the general case with non-standard divisors (which can include numbers like $(\omega^\omega-1)/(\omega-1)$ with infinitely many segments), I expect the binary expansion to follow a finite hierarchy of nested cycles, all of which can be evaluated modulo any standard integer. [Though I would appreciate it if someone could point out any big issues in this rough sketch of a construction!]

By themselves, these encodings are simply weird algebraic structures with a number of additional operations defined on them. But since they represent subsets of a non-standard model of $\mathsf{PA}$, we know that any standard result from the operations will be indistinguishable from the same operations on $\mathbb N$, if you were to set $\omega=N!$ or $\omega=2\uparrow\uparrow N$ for $N$ sufficiently large. So I'm interested in whether there is any existing literature on sets like these $M_{\mathcal O}$s.
Also, I'm particularly wondering how many operations can we fit into $\mathcal O$ without running into computability issues. E.g., could we support $d_b(x,y)$ for $b=2,3,5$ simultaneously? Could we support it for every standard $b$? Clearly, we can't support every operation computable on $\mathbb N$, since that includes things like "Does this Turing machine halt before time $t$?", but we can still capture a surprising amount of elementary integer arithmetic.

The simplest way for a set of operations $\mathcal{O}$ to have the desired property is for there to be a model $\mathcal{M}$ of PA with a nonstandard element $\alpha$ such that in $\mathcal{M}$ the closure of ${\alpha}$ under the operations in $\mathcal{O}$ (which we'll assume for simplicity contain all the unary operations pointing at the standard naturals) is the free $\mathcal{O}$-algebra on one generator over some decidable theory.

Your statement of Tennenbaum's theorem is weaker than what he proves. Namely, you said that there is no nonstandard model of PA in which both $+$, $\cdot$ and $<$ are computable, but the actual theorem says that there is no nonstandard model in which $+$ is computable, and there is no nonstandard model in which $\cdot$ is computable. The $<$ relation by itself can be computable, since this is just a copy of $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{Q}$, which is a computable order.

@JoelDavidHamkins Ah, good to know; I'm not a proper set theorist, and I didn't look too closely into the precise statement. (I think I read that part at some point, but somehow conflated it in my head with $(\mathbb Z_p,+)$ not being orderable without dependent choice.) In any case, I mainly wanted to raise the idea that even though the full structure of a non-standard model is full of uncomputable dragons, there can still exist substructures that we can look at and manipulate explicitly.
